# Zend RestController > Get data using model or controller?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Iam building a Zend Rest Controller, and iam unsure about where to get the data from.
Basically i need to output the database data as xml format to the view.

Do i employ a model to controller data exchange,

or just query database and get the data in the controller itself, without the need of a model?

I see, most of the people are employing the latter scenario

Comment: Fetching data in the controller itself is a bad practice.

Comment: I dont see an example anywhere, which fetches data from the model, in the case of a RestController. Actually, i need to get a parameter and use it in my query for fetching data. Can anyone provide an example?

Comment: rest controller is the same controller as any other. Don't make difference - program as you always do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In additional to using a full MVC approach, I have read about people using [Zend_Rest_Server](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.rest.server.html), the argument being that you don't need to incur the overhead of the full MVC stack in order to handle such a request.

However, if you do choose to go with handling the request via MVC, then you can use a [context-switch](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.contextswitch) to change the view rendered.

However, in both cases, I believe it is generally preferable to have a service/model to access the data. This makes the access code more re-usable in other situations.